# Can I use Flutter without Dart?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart

Before you give me answers like: "Just use dart it is really easy to learn" you must know that I already KNOW Dart and Flutter. And I also KNOW that you can communicate between those 2 languages. However, I really don't like this language and I wonder if I could write a Flutter App without any single peace of dart line code. I want to write anything in C++ without any Garbage Collector or without any of those bad issues of dart. If you answer then just only answer if it can be done or not or not if it would be good or bad. I heard once that you can use Flutter without Dart but I also heard that you can't. If you know better then please answer.

Comment: No, the Flutter SDK is written in Dart.  The Flutter engine is written in C++,  but if you wanted to write directly on that, you probably would be better off writing directly on top of Skia.

Comment: You could definitely write a library that generate Dart code for you, but would that really be what you are looking for?

Comment: "without any Garbage Collector or without any of those bad issues of dart".  Why do you think the Garbage Collector is a problem?  It's an incremental collector running on a separate internal thread.  What is your evidence of "those bad issues of Dart"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. Flutter is a dart framework. Dart is the language. Flutter is not a language by itself at all. If you're writing "Flutter code", you're writing "Dart code"